# Add dragged item to the droppable jquery

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

Here im dragging an img whihc is draggable and i want it to get fit to the table cell which is droppable but unable to do so , can anyone help me with this , following is the line im trying to do so but unable to

$(this).add(ui.draggable.attr("id"));

Comment: You will have to `append` the dropped item to `droppable`. 
Share your code and probably you will help people answer your question better

Comment: can u plz help me with any better example to look into

Comment: look at some of the previous similar questions answered in this link https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+draggable+append+to+droppable